# How to auto generate the date a URL was last updated?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to find out if it's possible to fetch the date a URL was last updated. So column A I'd have the URL and column B the data would auto generate. I'm guessing this would be done using some sort of script, but I don't know where to start. Googling isn't helping much.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this can be done with a script. Keep in mind that Google services are subject to [various quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas); if you ask it to do too much, it may well refuse. How much is too much depends on circumstances: e.g., if some of the websites take a long time to reach, the script may have problems with maximum execution time (6 minutes).

Here is the script. It takes URLs from the column A of the active sheet, and records the "Last-Modified" date returned by the server in the B column. Each URL is tested for having `http` at the beginning, to avoid making weird fetch calls when the column happens to contain something else.

To refresh the data periodically, you may want to run the script daily with a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

```
function testurl() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2);
  var urls = range.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
    if (/^http/.test(urls[i][0])) {
      urls[i][1] = UrlFetchApp.fetch(urls[i][0]).getHeaders()['Last-Modified'];
    }
  }
  range.setValues(urls);
}
```

Sample output:

```
+---+----------------------------------+-------------------------------+
|   |                A                 |               B               |
+---+----------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| 1 | http://blog.stackoverflow.com    | Tue, 29 Mar 2016 18:02:37 GMT |
| 2 | http://webapps.stackexchange.com | Sun, 03 Apr 2016 00:50:59 GMT |
+---+----------------------------------+-------------------------------+
```